# Hpload an image into SQL Server database using c# and asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Before I ask the question I just want to say that I have gone through a lot of other similar questions like this and they didn't help that's why i decided to ask mine.

Ok, so I'm trying to upload a selected image to the database when an Upload button is clicked, the front-end was written in ASP.NET and the back-end in C#.

This is my code:

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("i put my connection string here");
    con.Open();

    int length = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;
    byte[] pic = new byte[length];

    FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(pic, 0, length);

    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("insert into LogHelp (file) values (@image)", con);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", pic);

    com.ExecuteNonQuery();

    con.close();
}
```

Now I'm using Visual Studio 2015 web form. When I run the code above, it throws this error:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'file'.

Please what exactly does this mean? And if you have another way I can use to accomplish the same task please I'm all ears.

Comment: Try rewriting your statement as `"insert into LogHelp ([file]) values(@image)"` - FILE is likely a keyword - you should avoid naming columns as keywords, but where this is impossible to change, surround them in square brackets

Comment: `insert into LogHelp"+" (file) values(@image)` you need whitespace after LogHelp, additionally why you have string concatenation here, just write it as one string. I'm voting to close it for typo

Comment: really? i've never know an RDBMS to complain at `insert into table(column)...` (and a quick test on my SQLS2012 here shows it doesn't mind - what version are you thinking of that does?)

Comment: Yes putting the square brackets worked perfectly @CaiusJard thank you.

Comment: It is *always* a *really bad idea* to use [SQL Server reserved keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql) as your table or column name. Try to use a **more descriptive**, more meaningful name than just `File` for your column - or if you **must** use such a keyword, then put in in square brackets (like this: `[File]`)

Comment: thanks for the advice @marc_s . I'll put that in mind from now on.

Comment: anyone know how to read from the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've since tested the hypothesis I put forward in my comment:

You need to surround your `file` with square brackets - FILE is a keyword in SQLServer

```
insert into LogHelp([file]) values(@image)
```

I disagree with the other commenter; I'm of the opinion that no database system I've used needs to have a space between the end of a table name and the opening bracket listing the columns to insert into. I do, however concur with his observation that there is no need to write the SQL as two strings that are concatenated (`"INSERT..."+" values..."`) in your code though

Consider NOT getting into the `AddWithValue` habit, for reasons set out here: https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: well that was actually the problem, once i put the square brackets it worked perfectly. Thanks a lot @CaiusJard

Comment: i'll take your advice and stop using AddwithValue a lot. Thank you.